# People Picker Postback issue in Sharepoint 2010, Infopath 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have a list which is degined in infopath form. It contains one people picker and one datetime picker which is disabled. Once after publishing the form the server side(In browser) when I put the user name in the person picker and resolve it, that causes a slight refresh or postback and  the datetime picker becomes visible(which was disabled). This problem is might be due to postback issue. Kindly give me a hand in resolving this odd issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any rules applied to the DateTime picker, like validation or formatting? If you do, check the DateTime picker properties and go to the "Browser Forms" tab. Check the Always option so the field is recalculated on every postback.

If this doesn't resolve the problem please provide more details about both fields.